# Access functions from sub-module from other sub-module

Tags: windows, module, rust

I am trying to split my program into a library that contains multiple sub-modules with structs and functions, and a main file that uses all of it. I want to have a sub-module that contains useful functions that aren't needed anywhere else but other sub-modules. However, I am having difficulties importing this sub-module into the other one. The cargo project is called eant_rust. My lib.rs and main.rs files are in the src directory. I have a folder called modules that the lib.rs file imports from. Inside the modules folder is a mod.rs file the two sub-modules I am having trouble with.

lib.rs:

```
pub mod modules;
```

main.rs:

```
extern crate eant_rust;

fn main() {}
```

mod.rs (inside modules folder with the two sub-modules):

```
pub mod network;
```

functions.rs (one sub-module):

```
pub fn reverse() {}
pub fn sum_vec() {}
```

network.rs (the other one):

```
use modules::functions;
functions::reverse();
functions::sum_vec();
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:
error: unresolved import `modules::functions`. There is no `functions` in `modules`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly your files look like this:

```
lib -
    |- lib.rs
    |- main.rs
    |- modules -
               |- mod.rs
               |- functions.rs
               |- network.rs
```

From what you wrote in `network.rs` you should be able to use `modules::functions` however it seems you did not include it in modules/mod.rs

So add a line with `mod functions;` to modules/mod.rs.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Also, in order to use anything from modules, don't you need to use `pub`?

Comment: Not if you are in the same crate, pub is used to export parts of your crate so that others can access it. Check out: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#visibility-and-privacy